# angular 2 date pipe add or sub hour

Tags: date, angular, filter, pipe

I have a problem about new **Angular 2 Date Pipe.**

I have a date value which is;

```
let myDate = '2017-01-31T17:53:36'
```

And I use Date Pipe as formatter to display in view like this;

```
{{myDate | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm' }}
```

But it shows me the local time which is adding +3 hour.

```
31/01/2017 20:53
```

I would like to show which exact time is;

```
31/01/2017 17:53
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "exact time?" is that the time on the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope it will help:
https://www.reddit.com/r/Angular2/comments/4so1j7/how_to_set_locale_for_datepipe/

> This is a pipe, there for you use it in your template. Basically in my case, my webApi returns full date format (ie. Tue Dec 15 2015 13:30:32 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)). So in my pipe I do new Date(value) which will create a javascript Date object from the string. If your date returned from the http call doesn't contain any localisation information, then the parsed date will be taken like if it was in your current timezone.

Comment: this is what I exactly did on pipe;

export class UtcDatePipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: string, format: string): string {
        let momentDate = moment(new Date(value)).utcOffset(0);
        if (momentDate.isValid())
            return momentDate.format(format);
        else
            return value;
    }

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the `PipeTransform` and create your own `UTCDatePipe`, then override the `transform` method and the first parameter that will be the date do a `.UTC()` and then apply the given pattern (provided as the second parameter in the transform method) and return that.

Here is the DatePipe code as a reference:
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.0.0-beta.2/modules/%40angular/common/src/pipes/date_pipe.ts

Comment: thank you for your advice, but .UTC() is not native method on A2. Then I used moment.js via utcOffset() method. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

This method of your class will return your date in '2017 Jun 26 23:59:00' format.

```
    months:string[] = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
    getDateFormat(dateStr:string){
      let dateObj = new Date(dateStr);
      let year = dateObj.getUTCFullYear();
      let month = dateObj.getUTCMonth();
      let date = dateObj.getUTCDate();
      let time = dateObj.getUTCHours() + ':' + dateObj.getUTCMinutes() + ':' +dateObj.getUTCSeconds();

      let displayDateTime = date + ' ' + this.months[month] + ' ' + year + ' ' + time;
      // console.log(displayDateTime);
      return displayDateTime;
    }
```

One can also change the format by editing the 'displayDateTime' variable that this method is returning.

Comment: Please try to avoid just dumping code as an answer and try to explain what it does and why. Your code might not be obvious for people who do not have the relevant coding experience. Please edit your answer to include [clarification, context and try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)